# AWS RDS Postgres error while taking the dump

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, pg-dump, pg-dumpall

When I try to take PostgresDump (AWS RDS) the following error I am getting:

```
ERROR:  permission denied for relation dms_stats_detailed
pg_dump: error: query was: LOCK TABLE table_name IN ACCESS SHARE MODE
```

I am having admin permission though (with Master User).

Comment: Can you please share more info? How are you taking the dump? Via console or cli? If cli then what use you are logged on to?

Comment: also can you please share the pg_dump command that you are using, i'm suspecting there is not a mentioned of user while taking the dump.

Comment: "pg_dump -h rajtestpg12.something.test-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com -U test -f test.sql testdb"

when I do this, it works just fine for me. check if you are missing any of the params above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `pg_dump` with a database user (the `-U` option) that has permission to read the tables you are dumping.